# How to pass UlImage as Base64 String to Asp.Net Web Api

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-web-api, swift3

I have following code for iOS 10 Swift 3

```
if let pic = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
    let sss = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pic)! as NSData
    let s1 = sss.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
    // api call .....
}
```

in C# Web API I am doing following

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(defultdr["@imageString"]);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
// Convert byte[] to Image
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms,true);
image.Save(ImageDirPath + defultdr["@imageName"]);
```

where `defultdr["@imageString"]` contains the image data as Base64 string from iOS Wwift 3

but I am getting following exception

> Parameter is not valid.
>
> at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean
>   useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)    at
>   TWebApiSearch.Controllers.UploadController.ImageToDir(TRequest json)
>   in
>   C:\Users\tahmid\Downloads\APIWeb\TWebApiSearch\Controllers\UploadController.cs:line
>   53

on this line in Web API C#

```
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms,true);
```

What is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading the memory stream twice. Once when you initialized it

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
```

and second when you do the write.

```
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
```

No need for the second one as you already loaded the memory stream buffer when initializing it with the byte array.

Try this

```
var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(defultdr["@imageString"]);
var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
var image = Image.FromStream(ms,true);
image.Save(ImageDirPath + defultdr["@imageName"]);
```